# Java: reading and parsing XML file always return null

Tags: java, xml, readxml

i have XML file i try to read to a Document object:

```
<MCSA_Configuration>
    <Variables>
        <python27_path> C:\Python27\python.exe </python27_path>
        <python32_path> C:\Python32\python.exe </python32_path>
        <xlrd> xlrd-ok </xlrd>
    </Variables>
</MCSA_Configuration>
```

and i try to read it into Document object by code:

```
 import java.io.File;
    import java.text.DecimalFormat;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
    import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
    import org.w3c.dom.Document;
    import org.w3c.dom.NamedNodeMap;
    import org.w3c.dom.Node;
    import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

public static Document Get_XML_Document(String xml_file_path) {

        File file;
        Document xml_doc = null;
        // TODO code application logic here 
        try {
            file = new File(xml_file_path);
            if (file.exists()) {
                    DocumentBuilderFactory docBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                    DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
                    xml_doc = docBuilder.parse(file);
            } else {
                System.out.println("Error: XML File not found!");
            }

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
        return xml_doc;
    }
```

i always get xml_doc NULL
can someone help me solve the problem?

I Always get that the file doesn't exist, is use:
Document doc = XMLReader.Get_XML_Document("C:\MCSA\MCSA_config.xml");

Comment: Do you get `Error: XML File not found!` or a stack trace?

Comment: Check for the file whether it exists or not . If problem persists then post your stack stack trace

Answer (score 1):

instead of just checking `if (file != null)` check whether file exists or not `if (file.exists())`. Possible issue is file does not exist at that path

Comment: I Always get that the file doesn't exist, is use:
Document doc = XMLReader.Get_XML_Document("C:\\MCSA\\MCSA_config.xml");
and the file is realy there..

Comment: can you also try with forward slashes, e.g. `XMLReader.Get_XML_Document("C:/MCSA/MCSA_config.xml");`

Comment: Sounds like there maybe a trailing space in your filename or fileextensions are not shown in windows and the file is actually MCSA_config.xml.txt

Answer (score 0):

Your code working fine.

Check the condition after getting document

```
if(xml_doc == null)
  System.out.println("Doc is null");
else 
  System.out.println("Doc is not  null");
```

You will get

> Doc is not null

When you try to print the document it will give the output

> [#document: null]

You can perform operation through that document object.